# jQuery Mobile: pagecreate event does not fire when navigating from page to page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

playing with 2 simple pages and jQuery Mobile.

Trying to execute some js on each load of the page. For example show alert(1) for first page, and alert(2) for second one. When loading a page in a browser for a first time (or refreshing F5) it behaves as expected. However when I navigate from page 'one' to page 'two' using link - alert(2) does not show up.

The way how I want to execute some js on each load is as explained here - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/events.html - using `pagecreate`.

I found some similar questions here, but they do not answer what I need.
My question is - what should I change to make it working?

### My files here:

one.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>1</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('#divTestEvent1').live('pagecreate',function(event){
        alert(1);
    });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <!-- Start of first page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="divTestEvent1">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="one.html">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="two.html">2</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

---

two.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>2</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('#divTestEvent2').live('pagecreate',function(event){
        alert(2);
    });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <!-- Start of first page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="divTestEvent2">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="one.html">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="two.html">2</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the script in the head of two.html is ignored by jQuery Mobile. Please put this in both pages: (or create a JS file and include in both).

```
<script>
$('#divTestEvent1').live('pageinit',function(event){
    alert(1);
});
$('#divTestEvent2').live('pageinit',function(event){
    alert(2);
});
</script>
```

PS: Please use `pageInit` instead of `pagecreate`
See: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Another option is stick with your current code but enforce a refresh so the script in page 2 is executed, you can do this by setting:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="one.html" data-ajax="false">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="two.html" data-ajax="false">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: GerjanOnline - Part "Please put this in both pages: (or create a JS file and include in both)" did not work. Both JS file and in 'both pages'.
But second approach with `data-ajax="false"` does what I need. I'm loosing animation for pages change, but that is not critical in my case. So marking as answer.

Comment: Sorry I've overlooked something! You should use `pageshow` instead of `pageInit` because `pageInit` isn't called every time since the previous page is cached!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this automatically with just a single .live('pageinit') as shown below.

```
$('[data-bind="pageinit"]').live('pageinit', function (event) {
    alert( $('[data-role="page"]').attr('id') );
});
```

This will bind a page automatically when using attribute `data-bind='pageinit'`. The alert should be showing you the ID of the page , where the  must contain a `data-role="page"`.

**EDIT** 1 March 2013

Seeing the other questions being voted up with code that will undoubtedly require the repetition of code I thought to update my answer with: Enter the above code before the initialization of jQuery Mobile. Every page will be bound on the first time it's loaded (so on the `pageinit` event.  You'd have a setup something like this in your header:

```
    <script src="Scripts/latestJQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jQueryMobileDefaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/latestJQueryMobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

With my code above being included in the defaults page. This would make it fire also on the page first page being loaded the very first time it gets executed. This setup would give you a much cleaner setup than a repetition of code using a different numeric identifier for each separate page.

The event to which this can be used upon can also simply be altered. For all the events check the [jQueryMobile documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/), but for example: `pageinit` gets fired on the initialization of the page, therefore only the first time it's loaded, `pageshow` would be fired every single time the page is loaded.

Comment: can you explain why you are importing 2 **jqm** files (defaults + latest)? I understand that we only need one: `<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js'> </script>`

Comment: Yes, I can explain ;) If you read the instructions on jQM usage you'll find you need to set certain defaults BEFORE loading jQM. Therefore importing (and straight away executing) that one. You could take the jQM file and include the defaults at the start of the file, but this keeps it separate, easier to update and more organised.

Comment: thanks but I'm still a bit confused ... ... for instance: is the jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js file equivalent to your "jQueryMobileDefaults.js" or your "latestJQueryMobile.js"? thanks.

Comment: latestjQuery is the latest version jQuery core. Latest jQueryMobile is the latest jQueryMobile version. First load the core, which is needed later for loading jQueryMobile. After loading the core, load defaults for jQueryMobile, followed by loading the latest jQueryMobile.

Comment: an example of the defaults would be: `$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {

    //Initialize jQM    
    $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.allowSamePageTransition = false;
    $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'pop';
    $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = false;
});`
 So just this would be the entire file. Having this separate allows the jQuery and jQueryMobile to be updated easily. But these defaults need to be loaded BEFORE jQueryMobile.

Comment: very interesting ... thanks for taking the time to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

`pagecreate` is used for when the page is loaded. When you then switch between pages, it uses AJAX. To detect these changes, use `pageshow`:

```
$('#divTestEvent1').live('pageshow',function(event){
    alert(1);
});
```

Comment: Charles, I appreciate your input, but it did not work.
I added `$('#divTestEventN').live('pageshow',function(event){alert(N);});` in both one.html, and two.html. But that did not work. Alert only appears in the page you've entered first.

Comment: Please look at my answer, know the following: 
When the user clicks a link in a jQuery Mobile-driven site, the default behavior of the navigation system is to use that link's href to formulate an Ajax request (instead of allowing the browser's default link behavior of requesting that href with full page load). When that Ajax request goes out, the framework will receive its entire text content, **but it will only inject the contents of the response's body element (or more specifically the data-role="page" element, if it's provided), meaning nothing in the head of the page will be used**

Comment: GerjanOnline - yes I saw it. And about to mark it as an answer. Part of your answer worked for me. Sorry for delay with marking.